# Quarkus autogenerated JAX-RS resource throws PersistentObjectException

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I've created simple entity with two fields that extends *PanacheEntity* and then also an interface that extends *PanacheEntityResource*. Quarkus autogenerates all the endpoints for this entity. **GET**, **DELETE** work correctly but when trying to make **POST** request the application throws following: *org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.acme.Student*. Since the entire project is as simple as possible I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Student.java

```
package org.acme;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;

@Entity
public class Student extends PanacheEntity{
    public Long id;
    public String name;
}
```

StudentResource.java

```
package org.acme;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.rest.data.panache.PanacheEntityResource;

public interface StudentResource extends PanacheEntityResource<Student, Long>{
}
```

POST request body

```
{
  "name": "Vitaliy",
  "id": 5
}
```

Comment: What version of Quarkus are you using?

Comment: @geoand 2.14.2 Final

Comment: Can you try with `2.15.0.Final` please? If you have the same problem, please open a Github issue?

Comment: @geoand https://github.com/vitos-exe/getting-started/issues/1

Comment: I meant opening a github issue on the Quarkus repo.